# how use autocomplete jquery for 3 same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete

i used jqueryui autocomplete iwant be the same work for some input text 
but when i use $(this).val() for send value of textbox it show error and when i use (".Degree").val() shows and send to server first textbox it incorrect

```
function DegreeAutoComplete() {

        $(".Degree").autocomplete({

            position: { my: "right top", at: "right bottom", collision: "none" },
            source: function (request, response) {

                var spin = $(".spinnerDegree");
                spin.addClass("fa-spin fa-spinner");

                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("GetDegree")",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { search: $(".Degree").val() },
                    success: function (data) {

                        spin.removeClass("fa-spin fa-spinner");
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.PersianName, value: item.PersianName, id: item.Id };
                        }));

                    }
                });
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: '',
                results: function (resultsCount) { }
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {

                // ui.item.value contains the id of the selected label
                alert($(this).val());
                $(this).attr("sel", ui.item.id);

            }
        });
    }
```

when i use:  `$(this).val();`

> elem.nodeName is undefined

```
hooks = jQuery.valHooks[ elem.type ] || jQuery.valHooks[elem.nodeName.toLowerCa...
```

how can i fix it

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to ajax object inside it. Save `this` reference before using it in inside scope.

```
var spin = $(".spinnerDegree");
spin.addClass("fa-spin fa-spinner");
var $that = $(this);// save reference
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("
    GetDegree ")",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { search: $that.val() },//use $that var here
    success: function(data) {

        spin.removeClass("fa-spin fa-spinner");
        response($.map(data, function(item) {
            return { label: item.PersianName, value: item.PersianName, id: item.Id };
        }));

    }
});
```

**EDIT:**
Just checked [jquery UI doc](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)
You should use `request.term` thats it.

```
source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("GetDegree")",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            search: request.term
        },
        success: function(data) {
            //....
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you but i added $that.val() and i have same error

Comment: Check updated answer. Also follow the ref doc link for more info